# How to separate lines of a LaTeX eqnarray in Haddock markup?

Tags: latex, haddock

I can't seem to get this simple LaTeX code, embedded in a Haskell comment, to render properly when run through Haddock with HTML target:

```
\[
\begin{eqnarray}
y &=& f(x) \\
z &=& g(y)
\end{eqnarray}
\]
```

When I run the Haskell code containing the above comment through Haddock I see this in my browser:

> [ begin{eqnarray} y &=& f(x) z &=& g(y)
>
> end{eqnarray} ]

If I get rid of the double backslash at the end of the third line then both equations render properly, but they appear one after the other on the same line.

**Does anyone know the correct way to separate lines of a *eqnarray* when writing *LaTeX* intended for *Haddock* processing?**